# Event Person who Books Doesn't Attend Attend

Tags: civievent, civibooking

At our events the person who registers multiple people isn't necessarily going to attend the event.  Is there a way that I can allow for this so they don't become registered as part of the process of online payments?

Comment: could you use a Price Set which has a $0 option which is set to not count as a participant?

Comment: This goes some way to an answer but will they then get an invoice that includes them?  We have automatic invoicing and in an ideal world don't want to give a $0 option as this could be used by anyone and then give us an admin task we don't need in chasing up.

Comment: The $0 isn't making them a Participant though, so other than 'time wasters' what is the concern?

Comment: he headache of time wasters on admin manual followups is the issue with 0.  We allow zero for discounts.  Having a zero  price will allow anyone to choose zero and not pay the appropriate amount which will then give us more work on a skeleton staff.

Answer (score 2):

You can always register other contacts from the event registration page. It is not mandatory to be a current user.

In [CiviCRM 5.54](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/24167) each participant can be tracked by which user registered the contact for the event.

Comment: The issue with Register other person for us is that there isn't then a way to track who's registering people. That might not be the end of the world.  Is there any way to change the Civi Registration text that says not you - register someone else so it's more prominent? We have just upgraded to 5.53 which we'll be on for some time, I think.

Comment: Can you use word replacements?

Comment: You can use explanatory text at the top of the registration page, plus the profile you use for the form you can set the titles for the fields. So you could change it to "Attendee's Name" or something like that.